# Sanity check on users created via apt-get install

Tags: apt

Running `apt-get install` on a given package may result in users being added to the system.
Is there an easy way to verify (before installing the package), which users would be added and with what characteristics? I mainly want to ensure that:

- Users are created without a shell
- Users are created without a password

Comment: You may try to use simulation before actually installing the package using the `-s` argument on `apt-get install`. This shows the working of the command (that is all the information that is put up in terminal while installation of package) without actually installing that package. Run the command as `sudo apt-get install <package_name> -s`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like user creation is performed in the `preinst` or `postinst` files for the package, so a simple `grep` helped.

For packages which are already installed:

```
grep adduser /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.*inst*
```

For packages which still need to be installed, download a copy and verify:

```
apt source PACKAGE
grep adduser PACKAGE*/debian/*inst*
```